# XML Layout not displaying properly when the app is running

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[image: [Android App Running]()https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxyKO.jpg]

[image]

I'm having a problem regarding the XML Layout on the Android App Running Image the icons don't seen so right. It had doubled buttons, and the placements were not. The Android Studio does display it correctly but when running the app, I am having a distorted layout.

Comment: The phone always displays the right version.  Android Studio's layout editor is never more than an approximation.  If you want help, post the code of the layout and a picture or description of exactly what you want to change/what is going wrong

Comment: place your xml code here